# Where can I find the default timeout settings for all browsers?

Tags: http, browser, timeout, request

I'm looking for some kind of documentation that specifies how much time each browser (IE6/IE7/FF2/FF3, etc) will wait on a request before it just gives up and times out.

I haven't had any luck trying to get this.

Any pointers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts

Answer (score 27):

I managed to find [network.http.connect.timeout](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.connect.timeout) for much older versions of Mozilla:

> This preference was one of several
>   added to allow low-level tweaking of
>   the HTTP networking code. After a
>   portion of the same code was
>   significantly rewritten in 2001, the
>   preference ceased to have any effect
>   (as noted in all.js as early as
>   September 2001).
>
> Currently, the timeout is determined
>   by the system-level connection
>   establishment timeout. Adding a way to
>   configure this value is considered
>   low-priority.

It would seem that `network.http.connect.timeout` hasn't done anything for some time.

I also saw references to `network.http.request.timeout`, so I did a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=network.http.request.timeout). The results include lots of links to people recommending that others include it in `about:config` in what appears to be a mistaken belief that it actually does something, since the same search turns up this [about:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) article:

> [Pref removed (unused)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205140).
>   Previously: HTTP-specific network
>   timeout. Default value is **120**.

The [same page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) includes additional information about `network.http.connect.timeout`:

> [Pref removed (unused)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205140).
>   Previously: determines how long to
>   wait for a response until registering
>   a timeout. Default value is **30**.

Disclaimer: The information on the MozillaZine Knowledge Base may be incorrect, incomplete or out-of-date.

Comment: UPDATE: the `network.http.response.timeout` when from not being set in Firefox version 28 to a default limit of 300 (5 minutes) in version 29. [see this blog entry at morgb.blogspot.de](http://morgb.blogspot.de/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html)

Comment: I recently experimented with this in Google Chrome and Firefox, and so far there does not appear to be any HTTP timeout at all. I didn't start the tests simultaneously, but Google Chrome has happily been waiting for over 2000 seconds, and Firefox is coming up on 1500.

Answer (score 10):

After the last Firefox update we had the same session timeout issue and the following setting helped to resolve it.

We can control it with `network.http.response.timeout` parameter.

1. Open Firefox and type in ‘about:config’ in the address bar and press Enter.
2. Click on the "I'll be careful, I promise!" button.
3. Type ‘timeout’ in the search box and `network.http.response.timeout` parameter will be displayed.
4. Double-click on the `network.http.response.timeout` parameter and enter the time value (it is in seconds) that you don't want your session not to timeout, in the box.

Answer (score 5):

firstly I don't think there is just one solution to your problem....

As you know each browser is vastly differant.

But lets see if we can get any closer to the answer you need....

I think IE Might be easy...

Check this link
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050

For Firefox try this:

Open Firefox, and in the address bar, type "about:config" (without quotes). From there, scroll down to the Network.http.keep-alive and make sure that is set to "true". If it is not, double click it, and it will go from false to true. Now, go one below that to network.http.keep-alive.timeout -- and change that number by double clicking it. if you put in, say, 500 there, you should be good. let us know if this helps at all

Comment: For Firefox: I tried that, but my understanding is that "keep-alive" is the time that the TCP connection will stay open after the HTTP request comes back, so that if you make another request it'll reuse the connection and avoid the hand-shaking... Is that really the request timeout?

Answer (score -1):

### For Google Chrome (Tested on ver. 62)

I was trying to keep a socket connection alive from the google chrome's fetch API to a remote express server and found the request headers have to match Node.JS's native `<net.socket>` connection settings.

I set the headers object on my client-side script with the following options:

```
/* ----- */
head = new headers();
head.append("Connnection", "keep-alive")
head.append("Keep-Alive", `timeout=${1*60*5}`) //in seconds, not milliseconds
/* apply more definitions to the header */
fetch(url, {
    method: 'OPTIONS',
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    cors: 'cors',
    headers: head, //could be object literal too
    cache: 'default'
 })
 .then(response=>{
    ....
  }).catch(err=>{...});
```

And on my express server I setup my router as follows:

```
 router.head('absolute or regex', (request, response, next)=>{
  req.setTimeout(1000*60*5, ()=>{
     console.info("socket timed out");
   });
  console.info("Proceeding down the middleware chain link...\n\n");
  next();
 });

 /*Keep the socket alive by enabling it on the server, with an optional 
  delay on the last packet sent 
 */
server.on('connection', (socket)=>socket.setKeepAlive(true, 10))
```

**WARNING**

Please use common sense and make sure the users you're keeping the socket connection open to is validated and serialized. It works for Firefox as well, but it's really vulnerable if you keep the TCP connection open for longer than 5 minutes.

I'm not sure how some of the lesser known browsers operate, but I'll append to this answer with the Microsoft browser details as well.

Comment: And? What is the timeout?

Comment: Can you give a link?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.