# JQuery ajax call default timeout value

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, default-value

I got a bug report that I can't duplicate, but ajax-call timeout is the current best guess.

So I'm trying to find out the default value for timeout of a jQuery `$.ajax()` call. Anybody have an idea? Couldn't find it in jQuery documentation.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is browser specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is jQuery's ajax default timeout value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148830/what-is-jquerys-ajax-default-timeout-value)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a standardized default value. I have the feeling the default is `0`, and the timeout event left totally dependent on browser and network settings.

For IE, there is a timeout property for XMLHTTPRequests [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304105%28VS.85%29.aspx). It defaults to null, and it says the network stack is likely to be the first to time out (which will *not* generate an ontimeout event by the way).

Comment: So basically jQuery doesn't use any default value for it. The problem was reported on Safari.

I guess I'll just try to force some longish timeout value and hope for the best... Thanks!

Comment: @Marcus : did it actually work? I could not find whether timeout always overrides the browser's timeout value (even if your ajax timeout value is bigger than the browser's)

Comment: @AdrienBe At the time IIRC I couldn't duplicate the problem from the users bug report, but the timeout issue was the best guess at the moment. So I don't really have an answer.

Answer (score 24):

As an aside, when trying to diagnose a similar bug I realised that jquery's ajax error callback returns a status of "timeout" if it failed due to a timeout.

Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    timeout: 500,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus); // this will be "timeout"
    }
});
```

[Here it is on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tSW7M/).

Comment: Yes, see all error types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout

Answer (score 7):

there is no timeout, by default.

Comment: Could you share some source supporting your claim.

Comment: I've just tested it and can confirm this.

Comment: How can you test the absence of timeout ? It could be really long by default

Comment: some guys are still testing :/

Comment: @metamagikum I've not given up! It's been almost 8 years now, but I'm sure I'm going to get that timeout error any time now!

Answer (score 2):

The `XMLHttpRequest.timeout` property represents a number of milliseconds a request can take before automatically being terminated. The default value is `0`, which means there **is no** timeout. An important note  the timeout shouldn't be used for synchronous `XMLHttpRequests` requests, used in a document environment or it will throw an `InvalidAccessError` exception. You may not use a timeout for synchronous requests with an **owning** window.

IE10 and 11 do not support synchronous requests, with support being phased out in other browsers too. This is due to [detrimental effects](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) resulting from making them.

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this api info.

```
timeout
Type: Number
Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. A value of 0 means there 
will be no timeout. This will override any global timeout set with 
$.ajaxSetup(). The  timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; 
if several other  requests are in progress and the browser has no connections 
available, it is  possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In 
jQuery 1.4.x and  below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if 
the request  times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In 
Firefox 3.0+  only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; 
the script  will  run even if it arrives after the timeout period.
```