# Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        //do something
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Sometimes `success` function works good, sometimes not.

How do I set timeout for this ajax request? In example, 3 seconds, if time is out, then show an error.

The problem is, ajax request freezes the block until finishes. If server is down for a little time, it will never end.

Comment: You need a `,` there after the `}`.

Comment: take look at this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930759/how-to-call-a-jquery-function-onload-with-some-delay/12930892#12930892

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $.ajax timeout setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/jquery-ajax-timeout-setting)

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Please read the `$.ajax` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), this is a covered topic.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

You can get see what type of error was thrown by accessing the textStatus parameter of the `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` option. The options are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror".

Comment: regarding catching timeout error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout

Comment: Just doesn't seem to work for me, timeout: 1, confirmed it's being passed, just never times out

Comment: Make sure to wrap the entire $.ajax call with a try/catch.  Aborts are not caught by jQuery and will be thrown outside of the $.ajax call.

Answer (score 126):

Here's some examples that demonstrate setting and detecting timeouts in jQuery's old and new paradigmes.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KRXff/246/)**</kbd>

**Promise with jQuery 1.8+**

```
Promise.resolve(
  $.ajax({
    url: '/getData',
    timeout:3000 //3 second timeout
  })
).then(function(){
  //do something
}).catch(function(e) {
  if(e.statusText == 'timeout')
  {     
    alert('Native Promise: Failed from timeout'); 
    //do something. Try again perhaps?
  }
});
```

**jQuery 1.8+**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getData',
    timeout:3000 //3 second timeout
}).done(function(){
    //do something
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    if(textStatus === 'timeout')
    {     
        alert('Failed from timeout'); 
        //do something. Try again perhaps?
    }
});​
```

**jQuery <= 1.7.2**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getData',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        if(textStatus === 'timeout')
        {     
             alert('Failed from timeout');         
            //do something. Try again perhaps?
        }
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout:3000 //3 second timeout
});
```

Notice that the **textStatus** param (or **jqXHR.statusText**) will let you know what the error was. This may be useful if you want to know that the failure was caused by a timeout.

> **error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)**
>
> A function to be called if the
>   request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in
>   jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of
>   error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.
>   Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout",
>   "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs,
>   errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as
>   "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error
>   setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called
>   in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   JSONP requests.

src: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What's the difference between `$.ajax().fail()` and `$.ajax().error()`?

Comment: @GarciaWebDev - See [Call to jquery ajax - .fail vs. :error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13168572/402706)

Comment: +1 for including the jQuery 1.8+. Most other answers to similar questions only include success/error from <.

Comment: I tried to copy the JQuery 1.8+ solution, but it has a invisible character at the end <0x200b>, which compiles in a syntax error on the browser. ​

Answer (score 28):

You could use the `timeout` setting in the ajax options like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    timeout: 3000,
    error: function(){
        //do something
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Read all about the ajax options here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Remember that when a timeout occurs, the `error` handler is triggered and not the `success` handler :)

Answer (score 2):

use the full-featured `.ajax` jQuery function. 
compare with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543713/1689451 for an example.

without testing, just merging your code with the referenced SO question:

```
target = $(this).attr('data-target');

$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(response) { $(target).modal({
        show: true
    }); },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: H-Bahrami and Rudolf Mühlbauer thanks for reply but i am new in ajax so please clarify through my code...because i have already see these answer but i don't know What's going on..so please help me...

Comment: how I can do through .load() ? It is possible or not ?

Comment: @S.S, try looking for timeout in the documentation of load: http://api.jquery.com/load/  -- and i had a typo in my code, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check NginX settings also if your requests are going through NginX.

Ajax `options.timeout` is one thing but nginx request timeout might need adjusting also.

See https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-request-timeout-nginx/

Answer (score 1):

your request should be like below.

```
client.ajax({
               url:'web-url',
               method: 'GET',
               headers: 'header',
               timeout: 3000
          });
```