# Set timeout on AJAX without

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

I want to have a timeout after 2 seconds and then display "Unable to fetch page". But im not sure how to go about it... Heres my ajax code

```
// AJAX product options modal
$('.optionsTrigger').on('click', function() {
    var target, url;
    target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).load(url, function(){
        $(target).modal({
            show: true
        });
    });
});
$('#productOptions').on('hidden', function() {
    $('#productOptions').html('<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("img/loading.gif"); ?>" id="optionsLoading" />');

});
```