# Call to jquery ajax - .fail vs. :error

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

Which one should I use?

Is there any reason to use one rather than the other?

Is one better for error handling?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { start: start, end: end }
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#myElement').append(data);
}).fail(function() {
    // report error    
});
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { start: start, end: end },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#myElement').append(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // report error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The two options are equivalent.

However, the promise-style interface (`.fail()` and `.done()`) allow you to separate the code creating the request from the code handling the response.

You can write a function that sends an AJAX request and returns the jqXHR object, and then call that function elsewhere and add a handler.

When combined with the `.pipe()` function, the promise-style interface can also help reduce nesting when making multiple AJAX calls:

```
$.ajax(...)
    .pipe(function() { 
        return $.ajax(...);
    })
    .pipe(function() { 
        return $.ajax(...);
    })
    .pipe(function() { 
        return $.ajax(...);
    });
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.8, the deferred.pipe() method is deprecated. The deferred.then() method, which replaces it, should be used instead." http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/

Answer (score 36):

Just to freshen this up...

The success and error approach have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: This is actually a deprecation of `error()`on the `jqXHR` object, not `$.ajax` itself, which is what the user is referring to.

Comment: @AdamGrant, `$.ajax` _returns_ a `jqXHR`, so @slohr is correct.

Comment: You're right. I should reword my comment, the deprecation on `success` and `error` do not apply to the object level functions passed into `$.ajax()`

Comment: Spent few hours on this and yes, I found the deprecation is of methods and NOT of the options you pass to `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [chainable deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) promise style allows for a cleaner structure and the use of [always](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/).

```
let data = {"key":"value"}

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://example.com/api',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data), 
}).done(function () {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
}).fail(function (msg) {
    console.log('FAIL');
}).always(function (msg) {
    console.log('ALWAYS');
});
```