# Is $.ajax's error option the same as .fail()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone tell me if there is any difference between these two jquery calls?

```
$.get("/foo", function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    doThingA()
}).fail(function () {
    doThingB()
});
```

vs

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/foo",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        doThingA()
    },
    error: function () {
        doThingB()
    }
});
```

I'm refactoring some code and just wondering if these two are exactly the same.  I think if there is a difference it's most likely to be between `fail()` and the `error` option.  Grateful for any advice, thanks.

Comment: Yes. They are the same.

Comment: @Max Williams it looks meaning same as per my knowledge and here you can see as well **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062317/jquery-get-error-response-function**

Comment: That's a question that can be answered completey by looking at the documentation. Why didn't you?

Comment: @Tomalak sometimes the documentation won't mention subtle gotchas which can only be gleaned from the collective wisdom of the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sometimes, but not in this case, the answer you accepted does nothing but cite the documentation. You could have arrived on that level of knowledge on your own.

Comment: I waited a while for someone to say "Yes, they are usually the same, except in this one situation...".  That didn't happen, so i assumed that the documentation wasn't missing anything out in this instance.  I thought it polite to award a correct answer to *someone*, and thought it might as well be that one.    We've both got comparable rep, want to cut me a break here and give me the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to jquery ajax - .fail vs. :error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168572/call-to-jquery-ajax-fail-vs-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-longdesc

> - `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`
>     An **alternative construct to the success callback option**, [...]
> - `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});`
>     An **alternative construct to the error callback option**, [...]

The AJAX methods (`.ajax()`, `.get()`, etc.) return promises, which have these methods on them.

An example:

```
var promise = $.get("/api/user/" + userid);
promise.done(function () { /* ... */ });
promise.fail(function () { /* ... */ });
promise.always(function () { /* ... */ });
```

You can also chain the method calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference

[jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

It is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: success,
 dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: it's the `.fail()` part that i was asking about.