# Return alert message when fail validatemodel in web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a validation model attribute for asp.net web api, and I use jquery ajax call to perform the web api call. However, when my ajax call fail, the ajax error does not return any message in success or fail.

```html
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid) {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                 .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
  ...,
  success: function() {
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('fail');
  }
});
```

Comment: Is your c# code actually getting hit?

Comment: @MarkC. yes the C# code is getting in Valdiation Action Filter. However if there is validation error, it will not hit the web api controller. I suspect that this is the reason but i do not know how to resolve it.

Comment: @MarkC. got it i have wrong syntax. i put fail instead of error in my ajAx code

Comment: Oh, yeah, `error` was [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28305172/2679750) (if you're using a "newer" version of jQuery)..Good catch!

Comment: @Mark C. btw how do I get the response from ValidationActionFilter in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the response into your `done` and `fail` methods, simply do this:

```
$.ajax( "your ajax object" )
  .done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```

When you pass a parameter into the callbacks (`done`, `fail`), you are capturing the response. So, if you hit an API to get an array of strings, and it was successful, the array would be inside `data`.

Comment: it did not hit the api. It hits the fail instead if the validation fail. How could i get the  actionContext.Response from the ValidationActionFilter in js?

Comment: Did you try my answer?