# why do you need jQuery AJAX #then or #done or #fail methods?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In jQuery's aJax method, the object passed in includes success and error handling. Why then would you still need to use methods like #then or #done or #fail if it can already be taken care of inside the ajax request parameter?

Comment: It's functionally equivalent, but then/done/fail allows you to separate code that requests, and the code that receives the response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168572/call-to-jquery-ajax-fail-vs-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`success` and `error` can't be used to pass promises within a promise chain that are returned by `$.ajax`

You can't `return` anything to those methods the way you can within `then()`.

Consider a series of ajax requests that must all complete before some other code can execute.

```
$.getJSON(url)
  .then(function(resp1) {
     // this request won't run until previous one completed
    return $.getJSON(resp1.urlValue).done(function(resp2) {
          // can do things in individual request done also
    });
  }).then(function(resp2) {

     return $.getJSON(resp2.urlValue, function(resp3){
               // or do something in success callback for this request
            });

  }).then(function() {
     // do something here now that all the requests have resolved
  }).fail(function() {
    alert('I fire if any of the above fail');
  });
```

This chain won't work using success callbacks