# CORS - redirect to page which is being received by second GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I'm making AJAX requests (JQuery $.ajax) to load some content in my web page. However, after some time the user session is expired, thus it is required to authenticate again.

When the user is not authenticated, I received two GET requests from the website. One with the URL I requested in the AJAX (ok), and another which is provided by the firewall(?) of the server which causes the error of CORS, since this URL is not under the same server.

Example:

```
GET https://my.url.requested 302 Found      5ms
GET https://cors.url.which.causes.error.requesting.authentication
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cors.url.which.causes.error.requesting.authentication?blabla. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

What I need to do is to redirect to the second URL (the one causing the error). Because it is the URL which shows the authentication system/screen.

**How can I check whenever this error occurs in my javascript so I can handle (redirect)?**

Comment: Your page shouldn't be firing off random requests to the server -- should probably understand what is happening client-side before looking at the backend.

Comment: It's not random. I'm sending ajax requests when the user clicks in one button so he can view information of a certain row. I just wanted to know if there's a way to do a checking on client-side and redirect it. I saw that the first GET request has in its header the location. I'll try to grab that info...

Comment: "another which is provided by the firewall(?) of the server" led me to believe you didn't know where this is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some parameters in the $.ajax function. There's two ways to handle this problem:

1)

```
$.ajax({
    url: loadurl,
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        window.location.replace(authentication-url);
    }
});
```

2)

```
$.ajax({
    url: loadurl,
}).fail(function() {
    window.location.replace(authentication-url);
});
```

They are equivalent. Read: [.fail or Error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168572/call-to-jquery-ajax-fail-vs-error)