# Jquery async calls block page reload

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a function that performs a backup every 5 seconds. From time to time the target server of the backup is not reachable and the request stops until the timeout is reached.
Since this affects the user interface I execute this 'backup function' as a async ajax request.

```
setInterval("doSync()", 5000 );

function doSync() {    
     $.ajax({
         url: "backup.php",
         async : true
     });
 };
```

This runs pretty good in the background. 
But as soon as a reload of the page is executed, already waiting backup function calls will be completed. So in the worst case, if I have a backup with 30 seconds timeout, the user has to wait this 30 seconds before the new page is loaded.
That is not acceptable for the user.

Which strategy can I implement to avoid this? 
It would be ok to terminate the backup request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that issue is rather specific to the browser.
Indeed, most of them limit the number of parallel requests to the same host and that's why it "waits" before reloading the page.

If you're calling the exact same URL via your AJAX request as the one you're trying to reload, Firefox will not run more than ONE request at the same time. A simple workaround is to append a random query string to the URL.

Another option is to use the javascript beforeunload event to cancel your AJAX request : [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: The URLs are different, but anyway I learned from this answer that I should not overburden browsers with AJAX calls with something that should be handled by a separate job. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe think about setting timeout in your case. 
I also found similar problem already solved:  [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Comment: And with setting timeout I meant setting it a little less or equal to your 'sync' interval