# Check MySQL Database Multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to, or might not if there is another solution, check to see if a record exists in the database. I need to check this every 5 seconds or so while the user is on the page, when it isnt there i'll redirect them.

How can I check if the record is there every 5 seconds without refreshing the php page, but do it inline?

Any help would help greatly :)

Comment: You can achieve that using timer ajax calls

Comment: I have no experience of ajax, no idea how to use it, if anyone could help??

Comment: does your government block google or something?

Comment: [This is the simplest example I can find for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225641/2513523)

Comment: @Deforz There's nearly a [half-million questions on this site regarding ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5B). You should start there.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), but be warned calling a database that much can make your site slow. Obviously it'd take many users to make it slow, but this is a fair warning. You might also want to program a time out function where if the user hasn't done anything in `X` amount of minutes, don't submit `Y` into the database.

But here is the basics of what you're trying to accomplish.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myAwesomeFunction(){
        $.ajax({ url: '/path/to/mysqlcalling' }).done(function(data){
            //Call back data. The data variable is your callback data, though you will have to figure out how you want it to be used.
            setTimeout('myAwesomeFunction()',5000); //5 seconds = 5000 milliseconds
        });
    }
</script>
```

I'm going to assume you're using jQuery, otherwise this will be a painful step. You could also use jquery's POST functionality, but if you're not submitting data and are just calling the database, this is sufficient.

[More information on jQuery's AJAX Function.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[More information on jQuery's POST Function.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)