# Stop an ajax call if it takes to much to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, response-time

I have a search capability on my webpage where it searches for something on my DB using Ajax and returns results placing them on a modal box on the success function. After they are loaded it shows the modal. I am using django as a backend. Is there a way to stop the ajax call or maybe to know when the response is taking to long to happen? d

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

From: [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Thank you! Which other cases does "error" include? 500 SERVER Error? I think I have to check the status code on success if I want to catch the 500 correct?

Comment: 500 server error is tracted as error, to get it's error code catch it from the response. error: function(response){ if(response.status == 500){} }

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in jQuery

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "some.php",
     data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
     timeout: 4000 /*Miliseconds*/
   })
     .done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });
```

Vinilla JS i much more complex but the code you would end up with would be something like this

```
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // ALOT OF OTHER CODE....
   xhr.timeout = 4000;
```