# How to stop long polling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I start long polling in JavaScript:

```
getNewMessagesLong();

function getNewMessagesLong() {
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "listenMessageLong",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
        alert("success: " + data);
   }, complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
 };
```

So how can I stop this polling after start?

Comment: Websockets aren't an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: I don't use WebSockets. I just use Comet

Comment: I gonna do smth like this: var method1 = getNewMessagesLong(); And after i run this method ( getNewMessagesLong() ) , I can to stop it this way? ( method1.abort() )

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery

Comment: Set a flag that your `poll()` function checks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way gonna be right to slve this problem:

```
var $request;

function getNewMessagesLong() {
$request = $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "listenMessageLong",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
        alert("success: " + data);
   }, complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
};
```

And if you wanna to stop polling:

```
if ($request != null){ 
        $request.abort();
        $request = null;
    }
```