# how to limit load(decrease time-out) time for external files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have external files like images and `.js` files that some times because of server load or server down-time external files didn't load at all or load very very slow and slow down my main page loading.
I want limit load time (decrease time-out) for specific external file type
example :
original host : www.site.com
external host : www.external.com
when user open's www.site.com it try to load test.jpg file from external.com (that is currently down)
and it makes site.com load very slower then usual.

I want to limit load time I mean when a external file takes more then like 15 seconds just shutdown the request and load rest of website without external file.

Comment: You want to do this in php or on the frontend in JavaScipt?  You could use lazy loading.

Comment: i think php or htaccess  is better .

Comment: is this lazy loading work for .js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider asynchronous loading of external Javascripts and/or or place the loading at the bottom of your HTML, so that the browser don't need to wait for the slow servers before it can render the page.

Have a look at this ["Set timeout for ajax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery/5225641#5225641)
This works only cross Domain if the delivering Server allows you this by sending a [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work).

Comment: by external link i mean links like googleAnalytic i cant edit that or set ajax time out for it.