# Ajax call: Monitor if it is taking long time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I am firing an ajax call to one of my rails server using basic javascript call.

I want to know if there is a way to monitor the ongoing ajax call so that if it takes a lot of time to get the response , I can show an alert saying "Request taking lot of time. Please wait"

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: There is, it's called `setTimeout`

Comment: `jQuery config`, there is a `timeout` option..Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Just use a timer, that you clear when the call is done

```
var timer = null;

$.ajax({
    url  : 'someurl',
    data : {data: 'data'},
    onbeforesend : function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Request taking lot of time. Please wait')
        }, 2000);
    },
    timeout : 10000
}).always(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

The `timeout` setting aborts the call if takes too long.