# How to stop ajax call after 30 seconds if not getting response?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm getting to much time in get response of ajax call. Now i want to stop further process of ajax call if ajax taking time more then 30 sec time. Do any one know how can I implement it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the ajax code you are using? Do you use a library like jQuery or vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the documentation for ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Or this similar question: [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery) with the answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
    success: function (result) {                               
       returned_value=result;
    },
    timeout: 10000,
    async: false
});
```