# ajax requests hangs in chrome after connection lost

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've noticed some strange behavior in google chrome:

- if we send post ajax request when there is no network connection, we get err_internet_disconnected exception in console (and I think, it's OK)
- if we send long post ajax request and lose network connection during this request, google chrome doesn't abort it, there is no err_internet_disconnected exception in console and in devconsole's network tab this request is marked as pending (even after connection appear). In fact, this connection hangs and there is no opportunity to process this in js code (we expect to get ajax error, but nothing happens).

Have you any suggestions how to deal with this behavior?

EDITED:
a sample of code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://someserver.com/ws.asmx/ExecuteEx?pureJson",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: data,
   success: function() {
      console.log("success");
   },
   error: function() {
      console.log("error");
   }
})
```

I tried this code in chrome dev console in this page while editing this post. Screenshot is below.
The first request is my. I sent it, then unplugged network cable.
The second request was failed (because of unplugged network cable).
Then i plugged in network cable and the third request was successful. But the first request still has pending status (despite the loss of network connection).

[devconsole's network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6ug6.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your ajax code?

Comment: @DiskJunky , yes, I've edited this post

Comment: Have you set the `timeout` property? See [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery). That should abort the request if connection is lost after the time out has expired. Also have you tested any other browsers like FireFox or IE?

Comment: At least FireFox has the same behavior. I know about 'timeout' property, but we need to get a result even if takes hours to process request on server. But your mention about timeout property gives me an idea how can I bypass this issue using timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `timeout` property. That should abort the request if connection is lost after the time out has expired.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://someserver.com/ws.asmx/ExecuteEx?pureJson",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: data,
   timeout: 1000, // value in milliseconds
   success: function() {
      console.log("success");
   },
   error: function() {
      console.log("error");
   }
})
```

---

See also [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **timeout**
>
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. A value of 0 means there will be no timeout. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent.

Comment: What will happen to ajax if wait time increases (above 1000ms in timeout)? Will ajax keep on processing the request? What will happen if we wont' plugout the connection? and ajax keeps requesting the server and xhr show (pending) in red in console? How to deal with it? and How to replicate /test this case?

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper - The comments of an existing question is not the correct place to ask about your question or any new question. Please open a new question with your specific and relevant details. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the error function in $. Ajax ({ with this code and compare the results

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(request.status);
        console.log(request.error);
    }
```

I hope that help.

Comment: it doesn't help(