# How does jQuery handle timeout when internet connection get's lost?

Tags: jquery, timeout, internet-connection, wifi, ajax-request

I have an strange behavior of this synchronous ajax call when having a weak wlan internet connection on my tablet.

If connection is fine, I'll get "ok", if the connection is lost, I'll get "fail", but if the connection is lost during the request I'll get nothing at all.

My guess is, that the request was sent within the timeout, but while retrieving the data from the ajax call the internet connection broke down and so neither done nor fail will be fired. Do you have any ideas what kind of problem may occur? The best solution should be, that it fires "fail" when connection gets los during the request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/callme.php',
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    timeout: 3000
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert("ok");
})
.fail(function(data) {
    alert("fail");
});
```

**EDIT:**
Not, this is not a duplicate question... the timeout doesn't work as expected when you have a weak connection with temporary internet loses.

Comment: The problem is moot anyway, as you shouldn't be using synchronous request. Remove `async: false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Not, this is not a duplicate question... the timeout doesn't work as expected when you have a weak connection with temporary internet loses.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I need an synchronous request in this case...

Comment: Are you making the request in the `onbeforeunload` event? That's the only time a synchronous request is applicable. Otherwise you should be using the async callback pattern.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: In the software the ajax request is send to book a transaction. I have to do this in a synchronous request beacuse I have to wait for the response (ok/not ok) to decide afterwards how to continue in the software.

Comment: That is exactly why you *should be using an async* request. Use the callback pattern properly and you will have no issues.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I'll do it with async callbacks... it is possible to refactor the software.