# PHP: Page 404 Not Found on Ajax Request

Tags: php, ajax, exec, ajaxform

So, I'm sending a form with `ajaxForm` which will send data, open spinner.gif, then on success close spinner and reload the page:

```
$('#form').ajaxForm({
beforeSubmit:function(){
    spinnerLoad();},
success: function(data){
    spinnerDone();      
    window.location.href ="sample.php";
}
});
```

Then the form is handled like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
  exec("/directory/script.php $args");
}
```

So this page, 'script.php' executes another script on DB, so it may take a long time. When there is not many data, it works fine, but whenever I have much, after a time 'script.php' wents 404, and the spinner.gif never stops.

I need to find a way to extend timeout somehow (**ajax timeout option seems not suitable**) or another way.
Sending the script.php page or the DB script to background is not ok - it must be finished in order to continue working.

I'll be glad to any comments/directions to look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery try this

Comment: *"ajax timeout option seems not suitable"* - Why not?  Isn't extending the timeout *exactly* what you want to do?