# Ajax Long Poll issues (Gateway 504)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok, I have been trying to figure out a way to solve my issue, and I am coming up empty handed. I have an **AJAX** call that is indeed working (I can see the rows being added to the mySQL database) however the ajax call times out from what I gather since after 60 seconds I see this in the console:

```
Error: Gateway 504 timeout.
```

Even with the timeout, I can see that the php script is indeed still working in the background and still adding rows to the database.

*I did try increasing timeout and* `set_time_limit(0)` in my code and still no luck. I think, based on my resourcefulness, I need to resort to **long polling**. Here is my modified javascript, trying to implement long polling;

```
$("#scan_library_submit").on('click', function(e){           
        var media_dir = $("#media_dir").val();
        var media_ext = document.forms['scan_library_form'].elements[ 'media_ext[]' ];
       if( media_dir =='' || media_ext == '' )
          {
          document.getElementById("scan_library_response").innerHTML = '<font color="red"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> All Fields Required.</font>';
          return
          }   
    this.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Scanning...';
    //ajax call to scan library
    (function scan_media_library(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/library_scan.php',
            type : "POST",
            dataType : 'json',
            data : $('#scan_library_form').serialize(),
            success : function(result) {
                  if(result.code === 404){
                  document.getElementById("scan_library_response").innerHTML = result.msg;
                  return;
                  }else if(result.code === 200) {
                  document.getElementById("scan_library_response").innerHTML = result.msg;
                  document.getElementById("scan_library_submit").innerHTML='<i class="fas fa-check"></i> Complete!';
                  setInterval('window.location.reload()', 9000);
                  return;
                  }else{
                  scan_media_library();
            }}
        })
        }, 3000);
    })();
  });
```

I still get the Error Gateway 504... :(

also, a bit of an aside in this question. I would like to update a `<span>` with progress as the script runs; basically this script is adding data to a mysql table, so it could ping the table for row counts periodically. Would that be possible to implement? If so...how? Links to appropriate tutorials are appreciated, this is a learning experience to me!  As the AJAX request runs, it can ping the table every 3-5 seconds to see how many rows are added, then refresh a `<span>` with the result.

Comment: what is your php script, maybe only mysqli query is working; i would still check php.ini  and set max_execution_time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I left the comment , to what I think the real problem is, but you can set the timeout in ajax too:

```js
$("#scan_library_submit").on('click', function (e) {
    var media_dir = $("#media_dir").val();
    var media_ext = document.forms['scan_library_form'].elements['media_ext[]'];
    if (media_dir == '' || media_ext == '') {
        document.getElementById("scan_library_response").innerHTML = '<font color="red"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> All Fields Required.</font>';
        return
    }
    this.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Scanning...';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/library_scan.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#scan_library_form').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            alert(result.msg);
            callback(result.code);
            if (result.code === 404) {
                document.getElementById("scan_library_response").innerHTML = result.msg;
                return
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("scan_library_response").innerHTML = result.msg;
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        },
        timeout: 90000
    })
    this.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i> Complete!';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Unfortunately that did not work. I am looking at long polls... would this work or do I need to do something else to avoid the ajax timing out...?

Comment: @nicholas, most likely, its the mine answer in the original question