# Need to check jQuery AJAX response time and take some actions

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({  
        url: "http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com", 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 

        success: function(headers) { 
            language = headers['Accept-Language']; 
            alert(language);
        },

        //it doesn't work
        //timeout: 2000,

        error: function() { 
            //wait for 2 sec..

            //and if there are no response, do something.. 
        }
    });
```

I found `timeout: 2000` option, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but this should do the trick:

```
var cancelled = false;
var errorTimer;
$.ajax({  
    url: "http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 

    success: function(headers) { 
        if (! cancelled) {
            cancelled = true; // stop timeout code from running
            language = headers['Accept-Language']; 
            alert(language);
        }
    });

});
var errorCode = function () {
    if (!cancelled) {
        cancelled = true;
        alert('Took too long and now we ignore the response!');
    }
};
setTimeout(errorCode, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I just applied your answer.

Comment: So many negative answers! "Uh, you can't do that" isn't a very useful answer, and as I showed, it's also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How to handle a timeout is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/jquery-ajax-timeout-setting).

I'm not sure that there are events that can fire at different intervals up until you get a successful response.

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype is **jsonp** and it is clearly mentioned [`here`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script
>   will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting Docs:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Ajax requests are time-limited, so errors can be caught and handled to
>   provide a better user experience. Request timeouts are usually either
>   left at their default or set as a global default using **$.ajaxSetup()
>   rather than being overridden for specific requests with the timeout
>   option**.

Further:

> In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests **cannot be cancelled by
>   a timeout**; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout
>   period.