# How can I stop a page from loading if an external script can't be loaded?

Tags: jquery

I want a function that stops a page from loading if Google Plus One couldn't load in 5 seconds. In our country sometimes the HTTPS port is blocked by the telecommunications department and we don't have access to apis.google.com. It is not just slow, we realy don't have access to the HTTPS port. If this is the case I want some way of stopping the page from loading when we can't access https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js. How can I do this?

Comment: cannot you keep `plusone.js` on your own server?

Comment: also, `plusone.js` makes Ajax request that browsers cannot handle in case of direct opening that html file from your own disk but will work fluently with a server, keep aware of this.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: yeah when you put js file in your host nothing change at all.js file must comunicate to google server after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the Plusone script loads within 5 seconds, like so:

```
var i=0, checkPlusone = setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof gapi!='undefined') {
        if (gapi.hasOwnProperty('plusone')) {
             clearInterval(checkPlusone);
             console.log('Plusone loaded');
        }
    }
    if (i>5000) {
         clearInterval(checkPlusone);   
         console.log('Plusone not loaded');
         window.location = "http://www.mypage.com/no_plusone.html"; //redirect to error page
    }
    i=i+300;
}, 300);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LGZ4C/)

Comment: thanks for asnwer but thats not what i want.why redirect?if redirect happens then home page always redirect to home page.

Comment: just copy and paste this code and plus one will work??or i have to change it somehow?

Comment: In your question you write "I want a function that stops a page from loading if Google Plus One couldn't load in 5 seconds", this is it ? You can't really stop the page from loading, but good practice is to redirect to an error page instead, or do whatever you like, this checks if plusone is loaded within 5 seconds, what you do if it is/is'nt loaded is up 2 u.

Comment: Noone said anything about making plusone work, if you don't have access to the Google API, there's not much I can do about it ?

Comment: realy realy thanks.i thing my problem solved with one adjustment.i change redirect to stop(); but is this code usefull in any browser?

Comment: ok thanks its realy work:)) ..realy realy thanks.i just put this code in end of my body..before </body> tag and its work like magic:D...cause my page load is completed and then if plus one wont show up stoping the process.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could load the file with ajax and use a timeout.

Ctrl+F for "timeout" on the **[jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** page, and see it in use in **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/jquery-ajax-timeout-setting)**.

Comment: can you write code for me i am newbie in ajax.i just want to kill the page after 5 seconds how i can i do that??