# Jquery determine if load has taken longer to load than a set time

Tags: jquery, load

I am AJAXing in content from external pages. Most of the time the load takes less than a second, but is there a way I can fade in a div (lets say a preload div) which comes up if say the load takes longer than 3 seconds? So something like this...

```
$targetPoint.load($dataImportURL + " " +$rawCollectionPoint,function(){
    if (($(this).load >= 3))
    {
        alert ("Its taken more than 3 seconds to load");
    }                       
});
```

Comment: Search ajax + timeout :)

Here you go : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/jquery-ajax-timeout-setting

Comment: I don't think he wants to kill the request. I think he wants to notify the user that the request is taking longer than it should.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Then ignore my link! :)

Comment: Your absolutely right BZink. I just want to fade in a preload screen of some description if its taking too long rather than making the user waiting around wondering whats going on lol

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the JavaScript setTimeout function.

When you send off your ajax call...

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    alert ("Its taken more than 3 seconds to load");
}, 3000);
```

And when the ajax call completes cancel the timeout trigger.

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Edit: you may have to use the [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function from jQuery so you can take advantage of the beforeSend and success callbacks

Something like this...

```
var timeout;
$.ajax({
   url: $dataImportURL + " " +$rawCollectionPoint
   beforeSend: function(){
       timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        alert ("Its taken more than 3 seconds to load");
    }, 3000);
   }
   success: function(data){
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       $targetPoint.html(data);
   }

});
```

Comment: But that will just run the function as soon as the load function has completed. I need something which checks up on the load progress.

Comment: Ah just got your edit now :) that looks good I'll give this a try. Many thanks for your help :D

Comment: No it didn't work unfortunately :( Its missing some commas somewhere I think. I put them in place (correctly I think) but it still didn't work.

Comment: I didn't expect that you'd just copy/paste the code, so I'm sure there are some typos. I see the missing commas. Are you getting any javascript errors