# ajax timeout callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to run a function if jQuery's $.ajax function hits it's `timeout`?

i.e.

```
$.ajax({
...
...
,timeout:1000(){do something if timeout)
...

});
```

Comment: Maybe what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/jquery-ajax-timeout-setting

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(textStatus==="timeout") {
           //do something on timeout
        } 
    }
});​
```

For more information check out the jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

---

**Edited**

It's been over a year since I initially answered this and the `textStatus` possible values have changed to `"success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort",`or`"parsererror"`. For error callbacks, only the last four statuses are possible.

Also you can now wire your error handlers through the returned JQuery deferred promise object's `.fail` method:

```
var promise = $.ajax({ timeout: 1000 });

promise.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    if(textStatus==="timeout") {
        // handle timeout  
    }
});
```

Comment: Usually, good answers are explained, rather than just dropping a block of code.

Comment: @Paulpro I wouldn't agree.  It isn't explained what is passed to the error function, other than a string that would sometimes equal 'timeout'.

Comment: Worth mentioning: "The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to **time out before it can be sent**." In this case, only the `complete` handler is called: neither the `success` or `error` handlers seem to run.