# How to cancel an ajax request or third party js request when no response after x time w/ abort()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Curious what are some of your solutions, elegantly, that deal with block js calls / ajax calls that take too long reaching out to third party sites for data/info.

Lately, I've been contending with some scripts/ajax requests in which the server is either down or not responding and literally blocks my page. They are suppose to be async.

So, I want to abort the call after x time.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(result){}
});
```

then use: request.abort() if it takes too long.

But I am thinking I can use a deferred/promise here, with a timeout ability and call abort if my promise doesn't come back in say 1000ms.

Your thoughts?

My bad for not referring to the timeout attr of the ajax request. I didn't want to wrap the abort() in a setTimeout, but having the jQuery ajax api w/ timeout is what I need. I should have seen this. thanks all.

Comment: What about setting the `timeout` property on `$.ajax()` to 1000 and let jQuery take care of it?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Then check timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the timeout option: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(result){},
    error: function(xhr, status, message) {
        if(status == "timeout") {
            alert("Request time out");
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way can be using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
var abort_req = setTimeout(function () {
    request.abort();
}, 3000);
 //^ time in ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [jQuery $.ajax timeout setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/jquery-ajax-timeout-setting). JQuery AJAX has an optional **timeout option** that can be passed by milliseconds. You can process logic when the AJAX request timed out by passing a callback function to the **error option** like so:

```
error: function(x, t, m){
    //process error here
}
```