# HTML Server Status Checker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a plugin for a website that checks that status of an online server. No matter how much I searched, I could not find one that uses simple HTML or CSS. I *cannot* use PHP because Weebly doesn't seem to understand it.

I can use CSS, HTML, and Javascript.
All I need is something that tells the user if the server is online or offline.

Comment: You can always make a request with AJAX to the website and see if that succeeds or not, if it's an HTTP server.

Comment: Another super simple way if it's a website you're checking, load an image from the remote server with the img attribute `onerror="this.src='offline.png'"`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you're most likely going to run into cross-site issues though when trying to make a call to a page that's not apart of the current domain.

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ Does your code point to displaying a different image if the server is offline?

Comment: Do a little searching before you ask the question here is a question that is very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997675/checking-if-web-server-is-online-offline

Comment: The idea is it loads the image from the website that you're checking, but if it is unavailable (offline) it loads a local image called offline.png which could be something like "website currently offline"

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ That will not work because not all clients will have a certain "server offline" png willy nilly in their computers.

Comment: You misunderstand. The offline image won't be on every visitor's computer it will be with your HTML/js/CSS.

Comment: Also, the onerror attribute can do more than src replace. You can make it trigger text change etc with js

Comment: Oh I see! Yes, I used your method and it works.

Answer (score 1):

As sami kuhmonen said, you can make an ajax post and see if it fails:

**EDITED**
the html:

```
<div id="divtodiplaystatus"></div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
        $.ajax({
            //your server url
            url: "http://google.com",
            type: "post",
            data: "onlinecheck",
            success: function(){
                //function if server's online
                document.getElementById("divtodiplaystatus").innerHTML = "Server is online!";
            },
            error:function(){
                //function if server's offline
                document.getElementById("divtodiplaystatus").innerHTML = "Server is offline :(!";
            }
        });
```

Comment: I cannot add certain files to the website because my site is 3rd party hosted. I do not have root folder directory access. I can only add or remove HTML from the page itself. Is there a way to include that in an HTML string? (The server I'm trying to monitor is hosted by me however)

Comment: So you can't add it in <script>' the code from above </script>? I don't know if there is a way to solve your problem only with html

Comment: So just midify the code and add an function to display a Text via JavaScript innerHTML.... I will update the answer