# Form submit gives "Service Temporarily Unavailable" but not jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

We have a java enterprise application running on JBoss server which we access via an
Apache web server.

---

Scenario 1

When I am trying to do a time consuming form submit, I get the "Service Temporarily Unavailable" page in the browser. 
This was fixed by increasing the timeout parameter in Apache web server.

---

Scenario 2

However, when I try to Send the same form data using a jQuery ajax request, I don't get the "Service Temporarily Unavailable" 
page in the browser.

---

Questions

1.Why does not the the web server give the timeout error in Scenario 2 ?
I am aware the jQuery has a default timeout of 0, ie. no timeout. But won't the web server timeout since 
there is no response to it for the long time.

2.Are there responses being sent by Ajax to the web server regularly until the form submit completes to prevent the web server
from timing out.

Thanks.

Comment: You won't get a "Service Temporarily Unavailable" in the page but your xhr will eventually get a timeout error [that you can log or handle in other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout). Anything logged in the Network tab of Chrome console or Firebug?

Comment: @mccannf No. FYI In the Apache logs it said, that the favicon was missing. So we added the file and increased the timeout to solve the issue.