# How to return ajax error if url IP is incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, ip

I have been trying to get ajax to return an error for a post request that the domain IP was incorrect for.

```
    var serverAddress = "192.168.24.58"; // my current local host ip

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://"+serverAddress+"/electronTestPage/process.php",
        data: "action=testAjax",
        success: function(data) {

            alert("SUCCESS!!" + data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

If i change this to var serverAddress = "192.168.24.58**1111**" it will not throw any error.

However, if I change "http://"+serverAddress+"/**1111**electronTestPage/process.php"
 I will get the proper 404 error.

Is there any simple way to get ajax to throw an error on a wrong/non existent IP without pinging the ip?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Have you ckecked if the `complete` callback is called in this case?

Comment: I have checked with complete but there was no response

Comment: to be more specific, when the ip was correct there was a 'complete' response and when the ip was incorrect there was no response at all

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using? And what version of jquery? I have tested this with the hostname "192.168.24.581111" and several current browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, IE) and it always shows "Not connect. Verify Network.". It does sometimes take up to 2 minutes for the message to appear when the browsers waits for a timeout to resolve the hostname.

Comment: As per your suggestion I waited about 1 min and got a timeout and a returned error. This answered I wonder if  there anyway to shorten a timeout timer to like 5seconds or something. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` callback is called. But depending on the local network setup, it might take up to two minutes when using an invalid hostname until the browser realizes that the hostname is invalid and the `error` callback is called.

You can shorten how long the browser waits until it fails by specifying the `timeout`parameter in the `ajax` call in JQuery. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5225641/101087) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout) for details.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to know that sometimes different kinds of responses work through ajax may be too confusing and tedious, it is why there are different ways to return responses from PHP with AJAX with JSON.

The simplest way is if your PHP document are analyzing results, you can return through an array and a json_encode response and perform in a reply PARSE AJAX.

For instants:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var new_ip = '127.0.0.0';
    var parameters = 'action=check_ip&ip='+new_ip;
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        data:parameters,
        url:'myfile.php',
            success:function(response) {
                var answer = JSON.parse(response);
                switch( answer.status_response ) {
                    case 'success' :
                        alert(''+answer.message_response+'');
                        break;
                    case 'error' :
                        alert(''+answer.message_response+'');
                        break;
                }
            }
    });
</script>

<?php 

    //myfile.php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ( $action ) {
        case 'check_ip':
            $ip = $_POST['ip'];
            $theip = '192.168.1.254';
            if ( $ip == $theip ) {
                $response = array(
                                 'status_response'  => 'success',
                                 'message_response' => 'The IP is correct');
                echo json_encode($response);
            }

            else {
                $response = array(
                                 'status_response'  => 'error',
                                 'message_response' => 'The IP is incorrect');
                echo json_encode($response);                
            }
            break;
    }


?>
```