# error in ajax request to action controller asp mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, timeout

i have button that when you click on it 
it run ajax that send id to controller
now controller do something and its ok no error in server side,,
but in the action in controller i have code with restsharp that 
send request to rest web service its work fine too(*),
but this part(*) is in foreach and run for 5 or ... time
and when i do this things sometime ajax takes to long and the error part of ajax code is run
what should i do ?

ajax code:

```
             $(document).on("click", "#btn-submit", function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Panel/CheckRefOrderCode',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            factorrefid: $("#ref-check").val()
                        }),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.DntSuccess) {
                            } else {
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                        }
                    });
            });
```

action code

```
                        foreach(string s in str)
                    {
                        var client = new RestClient("http://**.com/api/v1/orders/status?support_code=71GD4A");
                        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                        request.AddHeader("token", "15befa43");
                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                        RefOrderJsonViewModel.RefOrderJson reforderbackJson =
                            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RefOrderJsonViewModel.RefOrderJson>(response.Content);

                        if (reforderbackJson.status.ToLower() == "ok")
                        {
                            performed += reforderbackJson.data.performed;
                            order_status += reforderbackJson.data.order_status + "^";
                        }
                    }
```

and i add this to web.config

```
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000000" maxRequestLength="262144" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a timeout to the ajax call:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btn-submit", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Panel/CheckRefOrderCode',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        factorrefid: $("#ref-check").val()
                    }),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    **timeout: 10000 // sets timeout to 10 seconds**
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.DntSuccess) {
                        } else {
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
        });
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout) on how to handle timeout error.

Comment: its not ajax time out problem..i see the error and the ajax not return a timeout error....and server side : the asp after ajax error still doing it job according to fidller

Answer (score 0):

the problem still is on;

but i use this

```
    Parallel.ForEach(myEnumerable, obj =>
{
   // ... 
});
```

instead regular

> foreach

and do the body of foreach in parallel,
and the time is decreasing,
the problem solved