# how to handle timeout and service not available in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, web-services, cordova

I am trying to handle following scenario using `jquery ajax`

we have a webservice that usually gets down for maintenance so when we make a call to webservice we want to show specific message i.e. "Service is down for under maintenance". Now to handle that we have written following code

```
$.ajax({
                 url: objWSConfiguration.VERIFY_USER,
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: jsonData,
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 async: false,
                 timeout: 1000,
                 statusCode: {
                    503: function() {

                         navigator.notification.alert(GENERAL_SERVER_DOWN_ERROR_MSG, null, "Hitachi", "OK");

                    }
                 },
                 success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR)
                 {
                    // perform a success processing
                    console.log("WSVerifyUser :response data " + JSON.stringify(responseData));
                    //Check Response Status
                    if(textStatus == "success")
                    {
                        if(responseData.status == STATUS_OK){

                            callback(responseData);

                        }else  if(responseData.status == STATUS_ERROR){

                            callback(responseData.errorMessage);

                        }

                    } else {
                        navigator.notification.alert("Connection Error, Please try again later", null, "Hitachi", "OK");
                    }                      
                 },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                 {

                     console.log("Error 1 "+textStatus);
                     console.log("Error 2 "+errorThrown);
                     console.log(jqXHR.status);

                    if(textStatus === "timeout") {

                        console.log("Fall here timeout ");

                        //do something on timeout
                        navigator.notification.alert("Request Timed out...",  null, "","OK");
                    } else {
                        // show error to the user about the failure to invoke the service
                       console.log("Fall here no where");
                        navigator.notification.alert(CONNECTION_ERROR_MSG,  null,"", "OK");
                    }
                 }            
             });
```

we have tried to handle it by adding callback for status code `503` but the problem is it never gets called when our service is down.

it always fall under `console.log("Fall here no where");` and textStatus is not returning `timeout` too in `error` function

but timeout and service not available are two different things so how can i handle it using ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if $.ajax error is a timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout)

Comment: No its not duplicate , here i am trying to handle two different things i.e. service not available and timeout.

Comment: you are logging `jqXHR.status`, can't you just check if `jqXHR.status == 503`?

Comment: Actually, I see you are already using `statusCode: {   503:.....`, is that not being called? Are you sure your webservice is properly sending a 503 HTTP header?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Facing similar problem, any solution identified?