# How can I abort an ajax request if it took a while?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, algorithm, performance

Here is my code:

```
$("input").on('keydown', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (tags) {
            $("ul").html(tags.output);
        }
    });
});
```

It works as well and all fine. Just sometimes `tags_autocomplete.php` returns a response after *8sec* *(which is too much)* or sometimes it totally fails and doesn't return a response.

Anyway, I want to make a `something went wrong` mechanism which should be run *4sec* after sending that ajax request. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: @chiliNUT While that may work, timeout would be a better fit. This would be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set timeout for ajax (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a timeout

You can catch error after timeout

```
$("input").on('keydown', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (tags) {
            $("ul").html(tags.output);
        },
        error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        },
        timeout: 4000
    });
});
```

Documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Well I need to know when `timeout` is executed. Because I have to show a pop-up contains *"something went wrong"* message. How can I when `timeout` is executed?

Comment: @MartinAJ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout

Comment: The `fail` or `error` callbacks will be used then when it times out.

Comment: @MartinAJ when it errors out, call a function from the error handling function to display an alert or some other message

Comment: @trevster344 `fail` and `error` are exactly the same?

Comment: Depends on which Ajax methods you use. On $.ajax I use the error callback. On $.get or $.post I use the fail callback.