# ajax request timeout 2min

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout

can ajax request set timeout more than 2min? When I set timeout value more than 2min, It has not effect. I test in chrome and edge, when request time more than 2min it will return timeout.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: requestURL || jsonServer(),
    dataType: "text",
    data: requestdata,
    timeout: 240000,
    success: successCallback,
    async: syncFlag,
    cache: false,
    error: errorCallBack || function (data) {
    requestErrorCallBack(data);
}});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout

Comment: Please also make sure that the server that the ajax is requesting has a timeout value according to your ajax timeout, otherwise, no matter if the ajax request has a timeout value, in that case the server will throw a timeout error before the ajax timeout that you set.

Comment: I add set_time_limit(0);  same result.

Comment: The error callback text="error", the console output net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue as well today. After few hours search, I found no any solution and explanations online. However, I kind of "solved" my problem luckily.

In my situation, I use webpack dev server to develop a SPA of Vuejs. The timeout issue actually fired by the dev server proxy. There is not any configuration for timeout in their [doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver). However, if you build your app and directly load your app without any dev server proxy, your code should be fine.