# Long PHP script - how long until the browser times out?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, timeout, keep-alive

This is important because I have a e-commerce site and I can't have a browser time out in the middle of payment processing! I have `set_time_limit(0)` in my PHP script so the script doesn't time out. But what about the user's browser? How long until it times out?

Note: data is *returned* to the browser only near the end of the script - most of the time involved is server work.

Also, is it possible for me to change the browser timeout length?

I need info for IE6+, Chrome, Opera, Safari, and Firefox. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts

Comment: Not really. Although the link given http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827 says IE is 1 minute the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050 says 60 minutes. I need clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use AJAX and let the process run in the background, but report once every x seconds / minutes back to the browser?

Comment: This may be what I need to do. How do I make the PHP script report every x seconds back to the browser, so it doesn't time out? Do I just have to add an `echo 'return text';` line of code?

Comment: You can turn it the other way around. Let a javascript on the page request the status every 5 seconds for example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the script execute as a cron job, and then save the report either in a table or as a file in whatever format you need?

Timeouts are going to vary not just by browser, but could vary from user to user. Firefox for example you can use about:config to change the different types of timeouts.

Comment: The script must finish instantly so people can get their digital downloads.

Comment: @Hope4You So, one Ajax call kicks off the process and another repeating one polls to see if the process has completed.  I wouldn't trust the browser timeout, even if specified, not to bite you here.

Comment: @Andrew How do I do the "polls to see if the process has completed"?

Comment: @Hope4You That is the substance of PeeHaa's answer.  You would have to set up a lightweight web service (which can just be a PHP script, for example) that you can call from Ajax, that will tell the browser when the server-side operation has completed.  A full description would be beyond the scope of a comment, but the Javascript setInterval function just might be involved.