# Increase time in REST-API, node + express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm generating a huge .docx document in a rest-api call. It takes several minutes for it to complete. Problem is the server somehow sends a "timeout" after a minute or so. Is there anyway to increase this time? Is it a browser thing or can I change it in express?

```
exports.generateDoc = function(req, res){
  var file = generateDoc(); //This takes several minutes
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.docx');
  res.end(file,'binary');
}
```

Comment: Most likely browser dependent.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout of an HTTP server in Node using the `server.setTimeout()` method which is described in the Node docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback).

There's also the Express middlewhere [timeout](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) which may help with Express.