# why does aws alb report elb_status_code of 460 for requests that the api has resolved

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have betteruptime setup to periodically ping my api. Today it reported the api was down for 2 seconds and i wanted to understand why.

After querying the aws alb logs i can see that there are logs corresponding that return a status code of 460. Note the target_status_code is empty.

[image]

if i search for these requests in my api, i can see it received the request and responded accordingly based on the trace_id.

[image]

Can you help me understand what might be happening here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Status Code 460 on Application Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986890/status-code-460-on-application-load-balancer)

Comment: @jordanm i don't think so, the second answer suggests logging the trace-id you might see if its not reaching your target. but i can see it is. So why is the target_status_code empty still

Comment: and is it likely that betteruptime.com closed the connection before watiing for the response :/ seems odd

Comment: I believe that just means that the ALB had sent the request to your backend before the the client closed it. 4XX errors are client side errors (although can be potentially caused by server side issues).

Comment: @jordanm so thats what im trying to determine if its a server side issue in this case