# http request thorows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after 4 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have an angular 5 node app. I am sending a request to node server and wait for the reply. Sometimes the response is sent from the server after 5-6 minutes. But **after 4 minutes** of waiting for the response, the http method throws an **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** error.

I tried to use timeout() with the method. But it still throws error after 4 minutes.

Is there any way to make the http method wait longer or to avoid this error?

```
const body = JSON.stringify(params);
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
return this.http.post('/api/execute', body, {headers: headers})
  .map((response) => response)
  .catch((error) => Observable.throw(error));
```

Comment: better start thinking on how to reduce the process time of the request, not how to increase the timeout limit

Comment: The time cannot be minimized

Comment: are you using proxying support?if yes share your proxy config.json

Comment: then I would suggest taking a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#13-long-running-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers have built in time outs, see this thread here [Browser Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts)

So, no, you cannot tell your JavaScript code to wait longer.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Keep-Alive header

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=560'});
```