# Can you increase apps script execution time to 30 minutes by upgrading to G Suite Business?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, quota, google-workspace

I have a web app that runs a doGet request. After upgrading to G Suite Business, this still times out after 6 minutes.

However if I run a standalone script, I can exceed execution time past 6 minutes.

The [quotas page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) under Current limitations > Script runtime looks like I should now have access to 30 min executions.

The app is executed as "Me" and "Anyone, even anonymous" has access to the app.

The WebApp is being used as a trigger to update spreadsheets. Once the spreadsheets update, the script then updates my database.

Screenshot of Executions Timed Out:[image]

Other notes: I have waited well over the 24 hour period for G Suite account to update, I am a paying customer, and G Suite Customer Service recommended I post here.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It could take some time before the qoutas and other stuff be update. When you made the upgrade? Have you already paid for it or you are running the trial?

Comment: Proof? How did you know that it times out at 6 minutes and who is the web-app set to execute as?

Comment: @TheMaster I added a screen shot to the original question so you can see the executions. It is set to execute the app as "Me"

Comment: @Rubén I upgraded 4 days ago. I am a paying customer. I spoke with the G Suite Customer Service and they confirmed updates occur within 24 hours so they recommend I post on here as Google does not have direct customer service support for Apps Script.

Comment: [Edit] to add that it is set to  execute as "Me" and "who can access" the web-app settings. Also explain how is the webapp accessed?  Although Having a webapp wait for >6 minutes is unreasonable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts

Comment: @TheMaster The WebApp is being used as a trigger to update spreadsheets. Once the spreadsheets update, the script then updates my database. I am in the process of creating a ScriptApp trigger as a workaround, they are just annoying as you cannot pass parameters.

Comment: The browser won't wait for 6 minutes though.

Comment: @TheMaster Browser is not waiting on request. Neither is server. Browser sends request  to server and gets a response back if the items in request were okay. The browser sends other doGet requests to check status of updating spreadsheets. The server then sends doGet request to Apps Script to update the spreadsheets. This is the request that times out. I'm close to having this solved by reworking it with triggers instead.

Comment: Try `curl webapurl/exec` or `curl -m 1500 webappurl/exec` and see if it runs >6 minutes

Comment: The [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) page no longer states there is a 30 minute execution time for any accounts although it currently appears to working in practice.

Answer (score 1):

#### Note: This seems not to be the case with OP and the question is not solved. The answer is  currently left as a possible answer for other users and maybe deleted.

If the web-app is set to execute as

> User accessing the web app

Then quotas applicable  for the user(6 minutes) will apply and not  the quota applicable for "Me"(30 minutes).

If it is set to Execute as "Me", Consider browser timeouts. Most browser's timeout is set to 300 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Updates can take more than 24 hours to go through and you may have to wait until the end of your billing cycle for quota changes to take place.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on Quotas for Google Services:

> Note: Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users. For more information, see the Help Center page on [sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852).

Resultantly, you may have to wait longer than 24 hours. I would suggest contacting G Suite support again with this information and ask them to clarify when this will be.

#### References:

- [Quotas for Google Services | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas)

#### Related:

- [UrlFetchApp quota limitation [165694310] - Visible to Public - Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/165694310)

Comment: Although it's not clear as crystal, that "Note" about "subject to customer limitations" only apply to gmail quotas. Why do I think that? 1. "Sending limit" links you to gmail 2. The star `*` next to  email limitation links you to this note, if you click it. On that note, I believe the issue was also  closed incorrectly, as the  Issue's OP's issue was "The urlfetch was called too many times  for one day"(There weren't any quotas related to that limitation, that'll get removed on update to gsuite, If I'm reading everything right)