# Angular 8 large timeout

Tags: angular, timeout

I'm facing a timeout issue with an Angular 8 app. My application needs to send a POST query to a a java backend server which will process a script for 7-8 minutes.The java app continues processing but because of the timeout, I won't be able to read the response .i tried the proposed solution in this link [Default and specific request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/default-and-specific-request-timeout?noredirect=1&lq=1) and i was able to decrease the timeout .Unfortunately when i set a large timeout value (900000) , i get a timeout issue after 4min . I'm not facing the problem when i test the POST query with Postman .

This is the HttpInterceptor .

```
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = new InjectionToken<number>('defaultTimeout');

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) protected defaultTimeout: number) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(timeout(900000));
  }
}
```

app.modules

```
  providers: [
    [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TimeoutInterceptor, multi: true }],
    [{ provide: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, useValue: 900000 }],
...
  ],
```

my service

```
  import(docType:any,docContent:any){
    let params =  new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('docType', docType);
    params = params.append('docContent', docContent);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${BASE_PATH}/repriseManager/importAgreements`,{docType,docContent});
  }
```

Console logs

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:3372
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:410
onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @   zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone    @   zone.js:1194
(anonymous) @   zone.js:3405
proto.<computed>    @   zone.js:1518
(anonymous) @   http.js:1792
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call    @   tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call  @   catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/timeoutWith.js.TimeoutWithOperator.call   @   timeoutWith.js:25
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
(anonymous) @   subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult   @   subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub  @   mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext   @   mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next  @   mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:53
(anonymous) @   scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @   mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call  @   catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call  @   catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
(anonymous) @   subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult   @   subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub  @   mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext   @   mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next  @   mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:53
(anonymous) @   scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe  @   Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @   mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @   filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call   @   map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe  @   Observable.js:24
push../src/app/features/dashboard/search-contract/contract-search-contract.component.ts.DContractSearchContractComponent.import @   contract-search-cont…ct.component.ts:180
eval    @   DContractSearchContractComponent.html:87
handleEvent @   core.js:29239
callWithDebugContext    @   core.js:30309
debugHandleEvent    @   core.js:30036
dispatchEvent   @   core.js:19859
(anonymous) @   core.js:28448
(anonymous) @   platform-browser.js:1032
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:423
onInvokeTask    @   core.js:26247
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:422
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask   @   zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask    @   zone.js:498
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1693
globalZoneAwareCallback
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: See the comments in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64659213/6513921

Comment: Michael thanks for the answer . i have changed the http request timeout of my navigator Firefox using this link https://superuser.com/questions/303217/how-can-i-change-the-connection-timeout-setting-in-firefox/303250#303250. i have always the same error .