# Is there a default timeout for jQuery`s getScript method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

I am using jQuery's `getScript()` method to load some third part js library, I am wondering whether there's a default time out value for this method. I don't really believe getScript will keep waiting until it gets a response, but I need to know how long before it quit and if that value is not ideal to me, is there a way to configure it? Maybe something like this?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

So it uses the default timeout which you can override as usually you do for `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: I just read through this similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507355/jquery-ajax-call-default-timeout-value), seems there is not a default time out value for the jQuery ajax, it depends on the browser itself, is this true?

Comment: This really depends what is going on in `jQuery.ajax`. The big difference is that `getScript` function is not using `XMLHttpRequest`. It simply adds to your document some remote javascript. You can try to have a look into jQuery source code and find there the place where they implement the callback and the timeout for this case. This will give you the answer