# Timeout times for major Web Browsers

Tags: timeout, browser

Does anyone know the timeout times for Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, IE 9, and Safari?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the default timeout settings for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers)