# HTTP client timeout and server timeout

Tags: http, request

According to this question: [Where can I find the default timeout settings for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers) each every browser has a default setting for time out

The default timeout in Firefox17, after checking `about:config` is 115s. However I have tested to run some request in which I timed and it returned a request after >150~ seconds.

So I wonder how does it works, shouldn't Firefox have timed out before?

Comment: There's many forms of timeout, are you after the connection timeout, request timeout or time to live (time before TCP connection stops)?

Comment: that timeout, if occurs, then it returns a timeout on a httprequest. is it not related to the browser timeout setting?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1343963/779408

Answer (score 40):

There's many forms of timeout, are you after the connection timeout, request timeout or time to live (time before TCP connection stops).

The default **TimeToLive** on Firefox is 115s (network.http.keep-alive.timeout)

The default **connection timeout** on Firefox is 250s (network.http.connection-retry-timeout)

The default **request timeout** for Firefox is 30s (network.http.pipelining.read-timeout).

The time it takes to do an HttpRequest depends on if a connection has been made this has to be within 250s which I'm guessing you're not after. You're probably after the request timeout which I think is 30,000ms (30s) so to conclude I'd say it's timing out with a connection time out that's why you got a response back after ~150s though I haven't really tested this.

Comment: Yep on my default install of Firefox 30,000 is the read timeout (time it takes to retrieve a reply back) although bear in mind I haven't tested whether Firefox obeys this, try changing it.

Comment: @starcorn not sure of the reason why it's so high maybe for very big payloads as it's roughly equal to 8+ hours.

Comment: what is de difference between connnection timeout and request timeout?

Comment: I think the 30,000 should be in ms, which is only 30 seconds.

Comment: 300s is the default HTTP timeout for Apache anyway.

Comment: What about `network.http.response.timeout`? What's the difference between response timeout and `network.http.pipelining.read-timeout`?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=592284, the pref network.http.connection-retry-timeout controls the amount of time in ms (Milliseconds !) to wait for success on the initial connection before beginning the second one. Setting it to 0 disables the parallel connection.

Answer (score -9):

go to the url `about:config` and paste each line:

```
network.http.keep-alive.timeout;10
network.http.connection-retry-timeout;10
network.http.pipelining.read-timeout;5
network.http.connection-timeout;10
```

Comment: This is terrible advice. Please never apply this configuration on Wifi or mobile connections. This would prevent you to display sites when your connection is being flaky or when a site is slowish.