# Serving a file to a user to download

Tags: go

I am writing a program that scrapes assets from a site(images & text), which will require the user to input which URL they would like to gather assets from. I then collect them all and zip all of them into a single file. I would like to then serve this zipped file to the user however I feel like the time to gather and zip the file is causing me to lose my connection to the user(10-15 seconds). Is there any way I can keep the connection to the user alive if this is my issue?

```
//Jquery post:
$.post( "GatherContent", { structure: userSelection, url: userURL } );

//lots of golang code server side to find all assets and compile them

zippedFile := compressfiles(directory)

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "applicaiton/zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='"+zippedFile+"'")
fmt.Println(zippedFile, zipPath)
http.ServeFile(w, r, zippedFile)
```

Comment: What you did so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: as a side note: you have a spelling mistake in your content-type.

Comment: 15 seconds could be okay if your users use default connection timeouts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582409/http-client-timeout-and-server-timeout); but as I see you use jQuery, so you could just make callback later when the work will be done on the server

Comment: What is the return type from compressFiles? What is zipPath?

Comment: @XyMcXface zippedFile is the name of the zipped file, and zipPath is the path to the file.

Comment: Have you tried just sending the headers first?