# How will timeout be determined when using fetch?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo

I have read a few questions and answers and found that we can not set timeout for a fetch request. In that case, what will determine the timeout of a fetch request? What if the server never responds to the fetch request? Is it expected that the fetch request is alive forever till server responds or client kills it?

Comment: I read this question, but couldn't find what the default timeout is determined by.

Comment: @DivyaKonda my understanding is this varies between browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343963/8526705

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a magic number that's specific to the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). As a matter of fact, it's not even mentioned in the specification. However, what you should think about is the browser in which you're using. That may play a role in how long a given request is allowed to live (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582409/http-client-timeout-and-server-timeout))

If you need to enforce a timeout, then I would suggest wrapping your `fetch` call within a custom timeout wrapper (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46946573/2415802))