# What is the default timeout for HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, http, timeout

When I load something in a browser, what's the default amount of time a browser will take to attempt to establish a connection?

Can this be increased in Javascript or HTML?

Cases that I would require this are server-side time sampling without a server-side loop, etc.

Comment: this will help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can't be set from your frontside as it is a server-side configuration.

Comment: You're saying a browser will never time out if the server doesn't tell it to?

Comment: That's correct: 408 Request Timeout
The server timed out waiting for the request.[2] According to W3 HTTP specifications: "The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: browsers have timeouts but they are usually much higher than the server timeouts for example IE is around 2m and so is Firefox