# How do I make a PHP page which will make the client time out?

Tags: php

I want to test that my client times out when a web server does not respond in time. I thought I could do this by making a PHP page that never completes the response, yet I don't want it to hog all the server's resources. I.e.  this is not an option:

```
<?php while (true);?>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: `<?php while (true) sleep (1); ?>` will work? Although normally you will reach the maximum execution time (30 sec) in PHP, so it won't really work that way unless you can edit that.

Comment: *sidenote:* you can config browser timeout to save you some time on waiting. Try changing settings of Firefox : `network.http.connect.timeout` and `network.http.connect.timeout`. For other browsers, read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsershttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); /* No time limit */
sleep (1000);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
   while (true){
         sleep (10000); 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: remove the while, it has no use just let it sleep

Comment: Oh cmon, that's my comment

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos as it answers the question you could've posted it as an answer yourself.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman you're sleeping 10000 seconds, or about 3 hours. The `while` is rather superfluous then since the delay already exceeds all other timers.

Comment: I just did with something a bit different. The while is correct, but not necessary.

Comment: im just used to write readable code, this way its obvious you never want to respond

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php while (true) sleep (10); ?>
```

This will work as long as the server has a timeout set.