# Has Chrome a timeout itself for web service calls?

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, web, browser

Before calling a web service from my web app, I set a specific timeout after which if I didnt get any response, the call ends up.

What if I set this timeout to, for instance, 10', is there another timeout after which Chrome does not want to wait for this response?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A webservice call is a regular HTTP call, so it's affected by browser settings regarding http.

I suggest you to look these answers :

General purpose answer :
[Where can I find the default timeout settings for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers)

Chrome focused answer :
https://superuser.com/questions/633648/how-can-i-change-the-default-website-connection-timeout-in-chrome

Unfortunately, AFAIK there is no setting available in Chrome to set the timeout.

Since last answer of the topic, I don't think Google has improved this but you could at least try the registry approach described there : 
Create KeepAliveTimeout and ServerInfoTimeout keys in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings with desired value in ms and check if it helps.

Additionally, very long http calls are not a very good design. If it's an option, it could be interesting to rework the server process and communication method to have some kind of "keep alive ping" on it, for example to display the progress in client browser instead of freezing it for 10 minutes.