# Automatic session timeout in web application (Angular 8 and Rest API) after 4 minutes

Tags: java, angular, servlets, xmlhttprequest

In my application developed in angular 8 and Rest API, I have a call that takes a long time than usual (> 10 minutes or more) in uploading certain documents.

But I can see in my browser's network that after 4 minutes my request gets canceled automatically and in my backend below error comes:

*Servlet.service() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application threw exception: java.lang.IllegalSta
teException*

In angular I tried below code but did'nt work out, I am using post end point:

`this.httpClient.post(endpoint, formData, { params: payload }).pipe(timeout(36000000)).subscribe((response: boolean) => {`

My questions:
1. Is this timeout happening from the angular side or restapi side?
2. How can I handle it?

In Rest api web.xml, I have below entry:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Please help for the same.

Comment: Are you using proxy config? (https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: Which browser are you using? It may be a browser specific setting. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342310/6513921

Comment: Yes,  "/api/rest": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8180",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {
      "channel": "intranet"
    }

Comment: Google Chrome. Is this related to browser timeout setting?